# QTCreator : Use qt project into another

Tags: qt, project, qt-creator

I was wondering how to use a QT Project into another in QTCreator.
I've created a subdirs test project with this hierarchy :

```
MainProject
  MainProject.pro
  ConsoleSubProject
    ConsoleSubProject.pro
    main.cpp
    firstclass.hpp
    firstclass.cpp
  GuiSubProject
    GuiSubProject.pro
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.hpp
    mainwindow.cpp
```

I would like to use the class "firstclass" (ConsoleSubProject) in GuiSubProject.
To do so, I've added this line in GuiSubProject.pro :

```
include(../ConsoleSubProject/ConsoleSubProject.pro)
```

When I've tried to build the project, it give me errors :

```
MainProject/GuiSubProject/mainwindow.hpp:4: error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory
```

If you have any idea about how can I use the class of project into another ?

Regards

Comment: What do you have line 4 in `mainwindow.hpp`?

Comment: I have #include <QMainWindow>

Comment: and you have `QT += gui` in `GuiSubProject.pro` for Qt include path ?

Comment: Yes, I have QT += core gui

Comment: And in `ConsoleSubProject.pro` if you have `QT -= gui` take care where is your `include(../ConsoleSubProject/ConsoleSubProject.pro)` in `GuiSubProject.pro`

Comment: I've tried to create a .pri file which contains only headers (.hpp) and sources (.cpp):  
  
    HEADERS += \  
        firstclass.hpp \  
      
    SOURCES += \  
        firstclass.cpp  
  
I've put an include(ConsoleSubProject.pri) in ConsoleSubProject.pro  
I've put an include(../ConsoleSubProject.pri) in GuiSubProject.pro  
  
But in the GuiSubProject file explorer I cannot see the header and source files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**MainProject/common.pri**

```
    INCLUDEPATH  += $$PWD/ConsoleSubProject
    SOURCES      += $$PWD/ConsoleSubProject/firstclass.cpp
    HEADERS      += $$PWD/ConsoleSubProject/firstclass.hpp
```

**MainProject/ConsoleSubProject/ConsoleSubProject.pro**

```
    include(../common.pri)
    QT += core
    SOURCES      += main.cpp
```

**MainProject/GuiSubProject/GuiSubProject.pro**

```
    include(../common.pri)
    QT += core gui
    SOURCES      += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
    HEADERS      += mainwindow.hpp
```

Comment: That works ! Thanks a lot !! Just a last simple question. When I create a new file I'll need to add the file manually to the common.pri ?

Comment: You can add file directly to common folder with Qtcreator (right click on common folder > add new) in the wizard you can choose to whitch project you want to add file

Comment: Ok, but if I would like to add a file to ConsoleSubProject and reuse it in GuiSubProject ?

Comment: In the wizard when you add a new file, in the last window you can choose beetween ConsoleSubProject.pro or common.pri (summary section you have a combo)  http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/images/qtcreator-add-resource-wizard3.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of include(../.....) in your GuiSubProject.pro its should be

```
    INCLUDEPATH    = ../ConsoleSubProject
```

Comment: I've tried that but I cannot use the class :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FirstClass::FirstClass()", referenced from:
      MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)in mainwindow.o